# Is there a way to optimise inputs to a python function which calls an executable?

Tags: python, keras, optimization, scipy

For example: I have an executable that takes 20 inputs from the command line. This can be called from python. The executable takes 2 seconds to run.

The result of the executable can also be interpreted by python. This result is required to be minimised which indicates an optimal solution.

What is the best way to find the optimal mix of input variables? I'm new to this field, but a neural net seems would have no training data. And scipys least squares (and similar) routines dont seem to handle well a slow function being optimised, it seems like it would take a very long time...

Any help, pointers and discussion would be welcome! Thanks

Comment: How do you define "optimal"? There are `scipy` methods which can search for the largest or smallest result.  Is that what you need?  And why is it async?  Computationally bound functions are usually not so.

Comment: The smallest result would be optimal. And the function could also by synchronous. I will remove the async from the question so it is clearer

Comment: The function you want is scipy.optimize.minimize. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: scipy.minimize is not what you want in 99.9% of all cases. It depends on your assumptions about your exernal function howewer. Look up `black-box or gradient-free optimization` if your external executable is not *smooth* (enough) and maybe even *stochastic*.